# In 'for (auto c : str)' what exactly is c?

Tags: c++, loops, range, auto

If I declare:

```
string s = "ARZ";
```

And then run the following code:

```
for (auto& c : s) {
  cout << (void*)&c << endl;
}
```

the results will correspond to the addresses of `s[0]`, `s[1]` and `s[2]` respectively.

If I remove the `&` and run:

```
for (auto c : s) {
  cout << (void*)&c << endl;
}
```

the address of `c` is always the same.

Presumably `c` is just a pointer into the vector and it's value advances by `sizeof(char)` with each loop but I'm finding it hard to get my head round why I'm not required to write `*c` to access the string char values.

And finally if I run:

```
for (auto c: s) {
  c='?';
  cout << c << endl;
}
```

It prints out 3 question marks.

I'm finding it hard to fathom what `c` actually is?

Comment: Are you familiar with _references_ in C++?

Comment: For this specific example where `s` is a `std::string`, then `for (auto& c : s)` is equal to `for (char& c : s)`, while `for (auto c : s)` is equal to `for (char c : s)`.

Comment: Yes, and it works as expected when I make c a reference with auto&. It's when I don't make it a reference I'm puzzled.

Comment: @NoComprende Understand. In the second case, `c` is simply an automatic variable of type `char` that is in each iteration assigned a copy of the iterated character.

Comment: https://cppinsights.io/s/51928cce

Comment: If it's a char what does the for (auto c : s) expand to?

Comment: @NoComprende Follow the link to cppinsights.io to see. Or, read YSC's answer. Note that it's not guaranteed that the address of `c` is the same in each iteration. The relevant part of the Stadndard is [stmt.ranged](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1).

Comment: The cppinsights explains it Daniel. Thanks.

Comment: @NoComprende OT: If you address your comment to _someone_, start it with _"@someone"_. Otherwise, you risk that he/she will not read it, since he/she will not be notified about its posting.

Comment: _"Presumably"_ Or, instead of guessing, look up what a ranged-for loop actually is and how it works, in your favourite documentation or book...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In 'for (auto c : str)' what exactly is c?

It's a local variable whose scope is the entire `for` block and has `char` type.

```
for (auto c : str) { loop_statement }
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    for (auto __begin = str.begin(), __end = str.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto c = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

On some implementations, under some conditions, since the lifetime of `c` ends before the lifetime of next-iteration's `c` begins, it gets allocated at the same place and gets the same address. You cannot rely on that.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the type, you can let the compiler tell you:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct tell_type;


int main(){
    std::string s = "asdf";
    for (auto& c : s) { 
        tell_type<decltype(c)>();
    }
}
```

Note that there is no definition for `tell_type`, hence this will result in an error along the line of:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'tell_type<char>'
```

And similarly

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'tell_type<char &>'
```

for the `for (auto& ...` loop.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Try `int a; int& b = a; tell_type(b);`. Your method goes through template argument deduction, which strips reference-ness. You'll need to use a forwarding reference (`T && x`) to get that to work properly.

Comment: @Sneftel actually no need to make up an example, I should have tried just what OP was asking for to see the mistake

Comment: Er, sorry, that won't work either, since forwarding references will reference-ize lvalues. But `tell_type<decltype(foo)>(foo)` (without the forwarding reference) should work.

Comment: @Sneftel thanks, please check again. With `decltype` there is no need for deduction anymore so I changed to `struct`

Comment: Looks good. Personally, I just hover over the variable name and let Visual Studio figure it out. :-D

Answer (score 3):

`c` is `char`.

The syntax can be misleading until you get it under your skin (but it makes sense).

```
for (auto c : s) //*distinct object* (think: a copy usually)

for (auto& c : s) //reference into the string (can modify string)
```

**Short:** use `auto&` when you need to modify the contents.

Answer (score 2):

> In '`for (auto c : str)`' what exactly is c?

c is a local variable with automatic storage within the scope of the range-for statement. It's type will be deduced because you used `auto`. In case of `string str="ARZ";`, the deduced type will be `char`.

> Presumably c is just a pointer into the vector

There is no vector, and c is not a pointer. It is a `char`.

Understanding what range-for does may help. It is equivalent to doing following (the `__` prefixed variables are not accessible to the programmer; they are conceptual for the behaviour of the loop):

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression;
    auto __begin = begin_expr;
    auto __end = end_expr;
    for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

Or, in this particular case:

```
{
    auto && __range = str;
    auto __begin = range.begin();
    auto __end = range.end();
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        auto c = *__begin;         // note here
        cout << (void*)&c << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Note that if you use `auto&`, then c will be deduced to be a reference to char. Applying the addressof operator to a reference will not produce the address of the reference variable, but instead the address of the referred object. In this case the referred object would be the character within the string.

Answer (score 2):

In this range-based for loop

```
for (auto c: s) {c='?'; cout << c << endl;}
```

there are three iterations because the size of the string `s` is equal to `3`.

Within the loop the assigned value of the object `c` is ignored and the object is reassigned by the character `'?'`. So three characters `'?'` are outputted.

The type of the local variable c is `char` that is the value type of the class `std::string`

In this range-based for loop

```
for (auto& c : s) cout << (void*)&c << endl;
```

the variable `c` has a referenced type more precisely the type `char &`. So in this loop the addresses of the referenced objects are outputted. That is in this loop the addresses of elements of the string `s` are outputted.

In this range-based for loop

```
for (auto c : s) cout << (void*)&c << endl;
```

there is outputted the address of the same local variable `c`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use references, the reference `c` is a reference to a character inside the string.

When you don't use references, `c` is a plain `char` variable, which contains a *copy* of the character in the string.

The reason the non-reference variant gives the same pointer for all iterations is simply an implementation detail, where the compiler reuses the space for the variable `c` inside each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto& c : s)
```

`c` is a [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/) to a character  (`char&`)

This loop is roughly equivalent to C:

```
for (char* c=str; *c; ++c)
```

---

```
for (auto c : s)
```

`c` is a character  (`char`)

This loop is roughly equivalent to C:

```
int i=0;
for (char c=str[i]; i<strlen(str); c=str[++i])
```

---